# Haram and halal parts of a slaughtered animal

Tags: halal-haram, dhabihah

Which part of a slaughtered animal is halal and which part is haram?

A few people say that tongue is halal and a few say tongue is haram. Also, contradiction on other parts like small intestine and large intestine, etc.

So can anyone give some references, please?

Answer (score 5):

(Sunni View)

All parts of the Zabiha is halal, with the exception of the blood since it's the only part that was explicitely stated as haram:

[image: Al An'am 6:145]

> Say, "I do not find within that which was revealed to me [anything]
>   forbidden to one who would eat it unless it be a dead animal or blood
>   spilled out or the flesh of swine - for indeed, it is impure - or it
>   be [that slaughtered in] disobedience, dedicated to other than Allah .
>   But whoever is forced [by necessity], neither desiring [it] nor
>   transgressing [its limit], then indeed, your Lord is Forgiving and
>   Merciful."
>
> [Al An'am 6:145](http://quran.com/6/145)

Comment: I've certainly read 'hadith' that the marrow from the neck is not halal. But it had no source.